# Why does PHP give me a fatal error for sending the (according to the manual) correct arguments to NumberFormatter's format()?

Tags: php, format, number-formatting, numberformatter, format-currency

From the manual at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.format.php

> public NumberFormatter::format ( int|float $value , int $type = ? ) : string

This code:

```
$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$string = $a->format(123, \NumberFormatter::TYPE_CURRENCY);
var_dump($string);
```

Causes this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ValueError: NumberFormatter::format(): Argument #3 must be a NumberFormatter::TYPE_* constant
```

Huh? Argument #3? There *is* no argument #3 (except in the procedural version)! And this code (thinking that maybe the documentation is wrong and nobody has ever spotted it before now):

```
$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$string = $a->format(123, 'USD', \NumberFormatter::TYPE_CURRENCY);
var_dump($string);
```

But it just causes this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: NumberFormatter::format() expects at most 2 arguments, 3 given
```

Okay... So how do you want it, PHP? Is it 3 or 2? I'm lost at this point.

**Important**: The reason I'm not using `formatCurrency` even though it is definitely a currency number, is that (in the real code) I'm trying to remove the currency symbol but otherwise format it as a currency. `formatCurrency` sadly ignores the `setSymbol`, but `format` honors it. That's why `format` is used in this case. Thus, please don't tell me to use `formatCurrency`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the documentation on the `intl` extension is a little incomplete or misleading. It would seem that calling `format()` without the second type argument will produce the output you want on your `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` object:

```
$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $string = $a->format('123');
// $123.00

$a = new \NumberFormatter('en_GB', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $string = $a->format('123');
// £123.00
```

The docs show that argument as optional but do not apparently explain how or when it should be used. In this case, omitting it seems to do the job.

Comment: Hmm! Makes sense in a way. Since the "currency type" is already set in a way. Seems to work. ("Seems" being the keyword... so far!)

Comment: Yeah. It bugs me that I don't understand it, I have been playing with it and have not found a way to make that parameter work. Maybe it is only relevant in a procedural context if the NumberFormatter object hasn't been created? I don't know. You can't call `new NumberFormatter()` without a type to begin with, so it's not like you can instantiate a generic one and set types at format call time /shrug.